# "The specified Tomcat installation directory does not exist" after reinstalling system

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I just reinstall my windows7 system, and now my project in eclipse can not run on the local Tomcat Server.

I have the error when I try to start the server.

```
The specified Tomcat installation directory does not exist.
```

[image]

How can I change the director of tomcat to run. For some reason, my disk E where install tomcat now becomes disk D. This mess up in eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

I guess your workspace still remembers paths relative the drive `E` that no longer work now because it has become `D`.

You could just go in eclipse into

```
Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment
```

remove the broken server and re-add it. Right click on your project to `run on server` and choose the newly created one.

However, since you have installed stuff on `E` which now is `D` you might run into other problems, therefore I would  suggest relabeling the drive, to do so please go to:

```
Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Computer Management
```

Then click on `Disk Management` under `Storage`. Right click on the partition now labeled `D` and choose `Change Drive Letter and Path...` and apply the changes you need, i.e relabel it with `E`.

Comment: Upvote!Thank you! I finally choose to change back my disk D into E again, the same as your second advice!

Comment: @Jaskey cool, your solution is workable too if don't encounter any other troubles. You're welcome!

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Found solution:

In the `Servers` tab double click on the tomcat server. In the `General Information` click on `Runtime Environment` then browse to the Tomcat installation directory, click `Finish`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:
Go to Window --> Preferences --> Server --> Runtime Environments

Under Server Runtime Environments, select the server configuration which is throwing the error and click on Edit.

Set the appropriate Tomcat Installation Directory by clicking Browse and choosing the tomcat directory.
Finally click Finish.

Then restart the server by running the project on server.

Answer (score 0):

1.To install tomcat7 in ubuntu. Go to **lib folder** and create a new folder with desired name like **Tomcat7** and give all permission to this folder.

2. Go to eclipse, select your project and click on **Window->prefrences->serve->runtime enviorments** and click on add button and select tomcat then press next, afterward a dialog will open and select the folder which one you had created in **lib folder** then press **download and install button**.
3. It will take few minute to download and after few minutes project is read to run with tomcat in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It took me all day looking for the solution. But it was simple just double click the tomcat 9.0 then it will tell you you do not have permission to open and promote you to continue. click continue. then will solve the problem.